# Sentry - adding arbitrary key/value pairs to the user context

Tags: c#, sentry

In the following [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?platform=csharp#capturing-the-user), it states that you can

> ...provide arbitrary key/value pairs beyond the reserved names and those will be stored with the user

In C# code, I have the following:

```
var _user = new {
  Login = "fred",
  EmailAddress = "fred@here.com",
  Name = "Fred Flintstone"
}

SentrySdk.ConfigureScope( scope => {
    scope.User = new Sentry.Protocol.User()
    {
        Id = _user.Login,
        Email = _user.EmailAddress,
        Username = _user.Login
    };
});
```

Is there a way to add `Name` (or any other field)? Or is the documentation just referring to tags?

Comment: Oh, I see. For other languages (like Javascript) the data structure is dynamic. Is there any way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom user data via the [`Other`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet-protocol/blob/master/src/Sentry.Protocol/User.cs#L59-L64) property.

The latest version of the [`Sentry.Protocol`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Protocol/1.0.5) has `Other` as a `IReadOnlyDictionary` which means you need to assign a new instance like:

```cs
var sut = new User
{
    Id = "user-id",
    Email = "test@sentry.io",
    IpAddress = "::1",
    Username = "user-name",
    Other = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Name", "your name"},
                    {"anything else", "whatever"},
                }
};
```

[This PR is making `Other` mutable](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet-protocol/pull/35) so you can add data like:

```cs
var user = new User();
user.Other.Add("key", "value");
```